# Java and iMacros

Tags: java, eclipse, macros, imacros

I'm trying to follow [this tutorial](http://forum.iopus.com/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=10899), regarding using Java with iMacros, but it isn't working. I'm getting an error saying "Could not find or load the main class" even though there is clearly a main class in the sample code on the website. Does anyone know why this might be happening? Thanks!

**Update**: Code sample

```
import com.jacob.activeX.*;
public class iMacroJACOBtest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Connect to iMacros Scripting Interface 
        System.out.println("Started."); 
        ActiveXComponent iim = new ActiveXComponent("imacros"); 
        System.out.println("Calling iimInit"); 
        // call iimInit() 
        iim.invoke("iimInit"); 

        // call iimPlay() 
        System.out.println("Calling iimPlay"); 
        iim.invoke("iimPlay", "CODE:URL GOTO=google.de"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a code sample?

Comment: Also, I'm using the Eclipse IDE.

Comment: Did you add the lib jars into your build path?

Comment: I did, in addition to the .dll in the path, but I'm still not able to run the program without it saying that it can't find the main class.

Comment: Did you use firefox in any of the steps? FF doesn't support java as of FF16 so that might be the problem.